# Remove html contents permanently to reduce browser load

Tags: javascript, ajax

I use **.hide** to hide html contents bysliding left.

but i have a doubt about hidden contents ! Can i remove those html content like **.empty** function while using **.hide** function because i heard **.empty** function removes html contents forever(permanently) so browser will not try to crash or stuck and i heard **.hide** function just hides the html contents so still there is a chance of crashing the browser or stuck the browser if i load something else via AJAX.

Any solution for this? can i remove those html content permanently like **.empty** function while using **.hide** function ?

```
$(".more").click(function () {
      $('#ss').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: What library are you using? jQuery?

Comment: Yes ! http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the .remove() method and assigning it to a variable like this:

var $element = $('#ss').remove();

The .remove() method returns the element that was removed, so when you assign it to a variable you can easily add it back in later.